# ¿Cómo administrar usuarios Firebase Auth desde Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs, firebase-auth

Tengo una aplicación en Vue.js, y como back end tengo Firebase, tanto para el Auth (email y contraseña) como para la base de datos (Cloud Firestore)

El problema radica en que no sé como hacer una administración de usuarios para un usuario administrador, donde él pueda crear o inhabilitar usuarios (no me interesa que modifique información o que el verifique los correos, me interesa que pueda crear usuarios y eliminarlos o inhabilitarlos desde una opción dentro de mi app.

El problema es que es que no encuentro la forma de hacerlo desde un Front End, solo veo cosas con back ends en node, Java y go, pero como no tengo un back como tal que yo haya hecho (ya indiqué que uso solo firebase como back y Vue como front) no sé cómo poder hacer esta página.

Si pudieran ayudarme o darme una idea/guía de cómo hacerlo les agradecería.

Comment: En la base de datos crea una registro que contenga los usuarios y ahi puedes crear un campo que sea el rol, es decir, si el usuario es _admin_ o no. Una vez tengas eso tienes que mapear tus usuarios de la base de datos con el usuario que ha iniciado sesión, y con eso ya podrías tener la administración de usuarios. Pero lo tienes que hacer tú a mano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La administración desde mi web app lo resolví con este tutorial de firebase para subir un API en Node en el hosting de firebase, cree un API en node JS para la administración de usuarios y la coloqué en Firebase y listo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer algo como esto:

[image: CloudFirestore Users]

Una colección de *Users* que tienen un campo *rol* (o perfil o permisos, como quieras llamarlo).

Si el usuario que ha iniciado sesión es administrador, es decir, tiene rol de administrador, que pueda gestionar. En caso contrario que no pueda.

Comment: No se puede así, dado que estoy trabajando con el componente auth() que no crea colecciones,tiene su propia base, por llamarla así, el SDK solo me permite hacerlo desde un backend, eso estoy haciendo, un back en Node para llamar desde Vue

Comment: No te hace falta el backend. Puedes crear los users a mano o puedes crear una cloud function que haga el trabajo por ti. Con una cloud function es como lo tengo montado yo

Comment: Sé que puedo crearlos a Mano, pero me refiero a la administración, lo resolví con este tutorial de firebase, cree un API en node Js para la administración de usuarios y la coloqué en Firebase y listo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8